# JSONObject toString() causes Out Of Memory on a 1495472-byte allocation

Tags: java, android, json, out-of-memory

I am using the following device to test my app:

[image]

I am posting a JSON string that is about 498467 bytes (0.48MB) in size.

When my app syncs this data, it fails when I `toString()` the `JSONObect` e.g:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
...
ClientMyAppApi.Upload(getContext(), account.name, jsonObj.toString()); // Out of memory here
```

Here is the LogCat transcript:

```
D/dalvikvm(21964): GC_CONCURRENT freed 690K, 12% free 10892K/12295K, paused 5ms+9ms
D/dalvikvm(21964): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 606K, 9% free 11196K/12295K, paused 57ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(21964): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.630MB for 662266-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(21964): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 431K, 13% free 11411K/12999K, paused 61ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(21964): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.157MB for 993394-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(21964): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 646K, 17% free 11734K/14023K, paused 63ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(21964): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.947MB for 1490086-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(21964): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 970K, 22% free 12220K/15495K, paused 69ms
D/AdapterSync(21964): uploadNewContent() JSON request size: 498468
D/dalvikvm(21964): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3172K, 30% free 10892K/15495K, paused 5ms+26ms
D/dalvikvm(21964): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 606K, 28% free 11195K/15495K, paused 56ms
D/dalvikvm(21964): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 431K, 27% free 11411K/15495K, paused 59ms
D/dalvikvm(21964): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 646K, 25% free 11734K/15495K, paused 61ms
D/dalvikvm(21964): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 970K, 22% free 12219K/15495K, paused 69ms
D/dalvikvm(21964): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1459K, 25% free 11742K/15495K, paused 74ms
D/dalvikvm(21964): GC_CONCURRENT freed 664K, 18% free 12726K/15495K, paused 17ms+12ms
D/dalvikvm(21964): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1930K, 18% free 12723K/15495K, paused 22ms+10ms
D/dalvikvm(21964): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 13K, 18% free 12716K/15495K, paused 70ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(21964): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1495472-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(21964): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 18% free 12707K/15495K, paused 114ms
E/dalvikvm-heap(21964): Out of memory on a 1495472-byte allocation.
I/dalvikvm(21964): "SyncAdapterThread-1" prio=5 tid=20 RUNNABLE
I/dalvikvm(21964):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4101ac78 self=0x2f5198
I/dalvikvm(21964):   | sysTid=22098 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=3325456
I/dalvikvm(21964):   | schedstat=( 5787106417 2132935545 325 ) utm=552 stm=26 core=0
I/dalvikvm(21964):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:~94)
I/dalvikvm(21964):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:132)
I/dalvikvm(21964):   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:124)
I/dalvikvm(21964):   at libcore.net.UriCodec.appendEncoded(UriCodec.java:119)
I/dalvikvm(21964):   at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:133)
I/dalvikvm(21964):   at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
I/dalvikvm(21964):   at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.encode(URLEncodedUtils.java:184)
I/dalvikvm(21964):   at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.format(URLEncodedUtils.java:163)
I/dalvikvm(21964):   at org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity.<init>(UrlEncodedFormEntity.java:57)
I/dalvikvm(21964):   at com.myapp.utils.NetworkUtils.makeHttpRequestWithParams(NetworkUtils.java:177)
I/dalvikvm(21964):   at com.myapp.client.ClientMyAppApi.MakeRequest(ClientMyAppApi.java:208)
I/dalvikvm(21964):   at com.myapp.client.ClientMyAppApi.Upload(ClientMyAppApi.java:395)
I/dalvikvm(21964):   at com.myapp.syncadapter.AdapterSync.uploadNewContent(AdapterSync.java:744)
I/dalvikvm(21964):   at com.myapp.syncadapter.AdapterSync.onPerformSync(AdapterSync.java:120)
I/dalvikvm(21964):   at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:247)
W/dalvikvm(21964): threadid=20: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
E/AndroidRuntime(21964): FATAL EXCEPTION: SyncAdapterThread-1
E/AndroidRuntime(21964): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
E/AndroidRuntime(21964):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
E/AndroidRuntime(21964):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:132)
E/AndroidRuntime(21964):    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:124)
E/AndroidRuntime(21964):    at libcore.net.UriCodec.appendEncoded(UriCodec.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime(21964):    at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:133)
E/AndroidRuntime(21964):    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
E/AndroidRuntime(21964):    at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.encode(URLEncodedUtils.java:184)
E/AndroidRuntime(21964):    at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.format(URLEncodedUtils.java:163)
E/AndroidRuntime(21964):    at org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity.<init>(UrlEncodedFormEntity.java:57)
E/AndroidRuntime(21964):    at com.myapp.utils.NetworkUtils.makeHttpRequestWithParams(NetworkUtils.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime(21964):    at com.myapp.client.ClientMyAppApi.MakeRequest(ClientMyAppApi.java:208)
E/AndroidRuntime(21964):    at com.myapp.client.ClientMyAppApi.Upload(ClientMyAppApi.java:395)
E/AndroidRuntime(21964):    at com.myapp.syncadapter.AdapterSync.uploadNewContent(AdapterSync.java:744)
E/AndroidRuntime(21964):    at com.myapp.syncadapter.AdapterSync.onPerformSync(AdapterSync.java:120)
E/AndroidRuntime(21964):    at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:247)
```

What and how is the best way to fix this out of memory issue?

Comment: can you split the json? I mean, a 450kb string alone... think about the space the jsonobject will take...

Comment: @WarrenFaith This is always an option. I notice that the app is using around 11MB of heap when it starts to run GC. Is my app using too much in the first place? I don't know what an average app should use.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a very "elegant" solution, you can try adding `android:largeHeap="true"` to your manifest. Try running with this, but I do not recommend leaving it there since it can cause a few performance issues.
That said, if it doesn't solve the out-of-memory problem, it might be somewhere in the JSON or the code itself.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the manifest option. I'll try and hold out for the "elagant" solution, as you put it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the [streaming approach employed by Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi): it seems to [allow incremental writing](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Streaming_API_Example) without the memory overhead suffered by the stock Android JSON library that needs to serialize the whole JSON object in `String` form before writing it on the connection stream.

Comment: I am actually doing what you suggest using `JsonReader` for my response. This however, is the request that is failing. It's failing before I can send it. Can I create and send a stream? Scratching head?

Comment: You should be able to [get an `OutputStream` from any `URLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getOutputStream()).

Comment: I guess I'll have to look into this: I'm using DefaultHttpClient: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html.

Comment: [With Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/performance.html#Request_Response_entity_streaming) it may [not be that simple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146692/how-do-i-write-to-an-outpustream-using-defaulthttpclient) indeed, but please keep searching.

Comment: Thank you. You've got me thinking!

Answer (score -3):

I check my AVD configuration. I have the same RAM amount. But, I have bigger heap size like 48 M. I think, it is worth to try.

Goog luck.

Comment: increasing heap size is not a real solution as this might just postpone the problem to the release... if the app can't handle so much data, the data should be reduces as best as possible...

Comment: The point is I need to get it to work on 16MB since this seems the default on smaller devices. The app seems to work ok so far on an HDPI device with 32 MB VM Heap.