# Ending a connection using my own HttpEntity

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to stream using a `HttpPost` request. To do that wrote my own `HttpEntity` as [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335638/oleg) suggested in [How do I write to an OutpuStream using DefaultHttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10152655/2478926)

My problem is that as the content length is not known my app gets stuck during the execution of the PostRequest even if I close the outputStream.

Is there a way I could terminate the connection without aborting ?

Thank's

Lukas

Comment: any particular reason not to use an InputStreamEntity?

Comment: I'm reading from a AudioRecord with isn't and inputStream.Thus it was easier and more convenient to write my own httpEntity than overwriting an inputStream with a AudioRecord.

Comment: Considering what you are explaining, I would probably have considered saving the audiorecord to a file, and upload it after.

Answer (score 0):

Read the spec for chunked encoding. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) it says you do not need the response header for length.

Note that the client, implementing a stream handler for the chunked response, knows that the stream sent by server is ending when it sees:

> 0\r\n

right near the end of the stream.